# Creating pages dynamically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am new to `iOS` programming, but I was wondering how apps like Instagram and others keep going to different profiles programmatically without knowing how many you are going to click. I understand `UIViewControllers` show the profile and you can create a `UIViewController` to show a profile, but how do they do it when they have a user click on a profile and another one on the same page ? It can be 20 or 30 pages. Do they just keep creating `UIViewController` programmatically ?

Comment: its one view controller... while going to detailsview controller, they pass the user id of whom you want to view profile...

Comment: @FahimParkar do they just simulate a transition when they go to a different profile? Also clicking back goes to the profile it was just recently at. Do app developers just add transitions to that also?

Comment: yes, there is transition...